# Missing Devel::Peek module

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, cpanm

My Perl has a missing `Devel::Peek` nodule.

---

```
# cpanm B::COW
--> Working on B::COW
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AT/ATOOMIC/B-COW-0.004.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring B-COW-0.004 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Devel::Peek
skipping X/XS/XSAWYERX/perl-5.32.0.tar.gz
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Devel::Peek' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for B-COW-0.004.
```

---

```
# cpanm Devel::Peek
skipping X/XS/XSAWYERX/perl-5.32.0.tar.gz
```

---

I assume it supposed to be included in my Perl installation by default, but it is not.

```
# perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 51 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2018, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

How can I fix this? What workaround should I do?

Comment: Maybe this is the issue - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1675130. Though this is for 5.24, but looks similar to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing the Perl package

```
yum perl-Devel-Peek
```